# How can I configure eclipse to show Assertion errors?

Tags: java, eclipse

My eclipse simply does not show the error in assertions... how can I change it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you check this: http://www.coderanch.com/t/416987/java/java/enable-Assertions-eclipse ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Asserations will always be compiled to the bytecode but are ignored from the Interpreter by default!

Open the project-propertys and go to "Run/Debug Settings", now edit your launch-configuration and add "-ea" argument to the VM-Properties.

Have Fun.